# Is there existing functionality in Alfresco Web Quick Start for an advanced search?

Tags: search, alfresco

I need to create advanced search functionality for my Alfresco website to search by custom metadata.

Does Alfresco provide existing functionality for an advanced search or will I have to code this using a new WQS page with a search form and webscripts?

If anyone knows this it would be a great help, don't want to reinvent the wheel and all that :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Given this information it is hard to tell how much effort it is to implement, but it sounds this could be done in a few hours - assuming you have a skilled developer.

Anyways, I would definitely not recommend to build a website based on quickstart unless you really feel comfortable coding "the Alfresco way" - that is Spring Surf and Alfresco Share. Of course you'll need some knowledge about how to code for the Repo as well. Keep in mind that quickstart as a best practice example is meant for educational purposes. Building on top of it most likely involves forking and starting your customization from there on. Before you decide to go this route, make sure a decent amount of your requirements are covered by quickstart.

Comment: I already have the majority of my website implemented, with most of the requirements being covered by quickstart. I just have a few tweaks like this to make to near completion.

Answer (score 0):

I am now developing a workflow search in alfresco. For me, I have to create a new page like alfresco advanced search. Here is **Share Advanced Search** http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Share_Advanced_Search customizing sample. 
Here is explanation about alfresco search. http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Search

I hope this may help you.